# Helm include formatted map from values.yml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a simple `values.yml` file for my Helm chart:

```yaml
DbMigration:
  Resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi
    limits:
      memory: 512Mi
```

In a definition for my database migration job, I have this:

```yaml
spec:
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 120
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: myMigrate
          image: myRepo/myService:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
            {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.DbMigration.Resources.requests }}
              {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
            {{- end }}
            limits:
            {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.DbMigration.Resources.limits }}
              {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
            {{- end }}
```

Is is there any way to simplify the `resources` area so that I can just include all the data from `$.Values.DbMigration.Resources`?  What I have works, but there must be a more concise way.  I tried using the `toYaml` function in a fashion similar to this:

```
{{- toYaml $.Values.DbMigration.Resources }}
```

However, that results in:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on myTemplate.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One of them is, instead of using `range` you can simply change the values.yaml into

```
DbMigration: |
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi 
    limits:
      memory: 512Mi
```

and then make a change in migration template as

```
  resources:
  {{- .Values.DbMigration | indent 12 }}
```

Please change the indentation accordingly.

Another method is to use `range` and `toYaml`

```
DbMigration:
  Resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi
    limits:
      memory: 512M
```

migration template

```
resources:
{{- range $key, $value := $.Values.DbMigration.Resources }}
    {{ $key }}: 
      {{ toYaml $value }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: AH HA.  I see what I was missing.  It was a Go template syntax error that was preventing me from doing what you have in there. Your answer made it blatantly obvious.  Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to render the block from values.yaml "as is" then toYaml is pretty much all you are going to need.

```
spec:
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 120
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: myMigrate
          image: myRepo/myService:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            {{- toYaml $.Values.DbMigration.Resources | nindent 12 }}
```

If you are still having convert to JSON error try to play with indentation a bit, it's all there is.